# Why is this deno test flaky, handling a rejected promise?

Tags: unit-testing, async-await, try-catch, deno

When running this test:

```js
const file = "exp.txt";

Deno.test("handle rejected promise", async (t) => {
  try {
    await Deno.stat(file);
  } catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof Deno.errors.NotFound) {
      await Deno.writeTextFile(file, "some text");
    } else {
      throw e;
    }
  } finally {
    await Deno.remove(file);
  }
});
```

When running it like so:

```bash
deno test --allow-read --allow-write exp.test.ts
```

the test succeeds.

However, when running it like so (adding the `trace-ops` option):

```bash
deno test --allow-read --allow-write --trace-ops exp.test.ts
```

it fails with:

```
./exp.test.ts (uncaught error)
error: (in promise) NotFound: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2), stat 'exp.txt'
This error was not caught from a test and caused the test runner to fail on the referenced module.
It most likely originated from a dangling promise, event/timeout handler or top-level code.
```

I have more involved code doing essentially the above failing even without `--trace-ops`. It appears to be more of a race condition or some timeout.

This is deno 1.28.3 and I've tried with several 1.2x versions with flaky results. However, it never bit me before running 1.28.3.

Note this way of checking a file's existence is suggested by the deno docs e.g. [here](https://deno.land/std@0.167.0/fs/exists.ts?s=exists)

Comment: I can reproduce this (but only with the `--trace-ops` CLI argument), and it seems like a bug. You can [open an issue](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/new) or [start a discussion](https://github.com/denoland/deno/discussions/new) if you feel inclined to do so.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that

Comment: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/16969

Comment: It looks like this was agreed to be a bug, and a fix was committed in [this PR](https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/16970). This question can probably be closed because there’s nothing actionable by the SO community here — the fix should be available in the next Deno release.

Comment: BTW Forget about the _I have more involved code doing essentially the above failing even without `--trace-ops`. It appears to be more of a race condition or some timeout._ that was another problem.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a bug and after submitting an [issue](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/16969) it was fixed and should be included in a new release of Deno (1.28.3+).